# Transpose Postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a query and I'd like to transpose:

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    COUNT(*) qtd
FROM 
    user_video_audience uv, video v, tag t
WHERE
    uv.video_id = v.id AND
    uv.watched = 'true' AND
    v.tag_id = t.id
AND 
    uv.created_date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours' )
GROUP by
    t.name
ORDER BY
    qtd desc
```

The result is something like

```
name       |     qtd
---------------------
Skate      |     45    
Surf       |     52
Snowboard  |     64
```

I'd like to transpose like

```
Skate   |   Surf   |   Snowboard
---------------------------------    
  45    |    52    |     64
```

I was able to make a query that works somehow;

```
select
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Surfe' THEN qtd END) AS Surfe,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Skate' THEN qtd END) AS Skate,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Kitesurf' THEN qtd END) AS Kitesurf,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Bike' THEN qtd END) AS Bike,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Natureza' THEN qtd END) AS Natureza,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Skimboard' THEN qtd END) AS Skimboard,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Skydive' THEN qtd END) AS Skydive,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Fotografia' THEN qtd END) AS Fotografia,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Snowboard' THEN qtd END) AS Snowboard,
    sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Mergulho' THEN qtd END) AS Mergulho
from (
SELECT
    t.name,
    COUNT(*) qtd
FROM 
    user_video_audience uv, video v, tag t
WHERE
    uv.video_id = v.id AND
    uv.watched = 'true' AND
    v.tag_id = t.id
AND 
    uv.created_date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours' )
GROUP by
    t.name
ORDER BY
    qtd desc) s
```

But the problem is that I don't know all the sports that can come up. Since it's a query for the last 24 hours, the value always changes.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! [This](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html) article may be helpful

Comment: The search term you need is "pivot table". It will turn up many hits and lead you to "crosstab".